# JAVA why is arrayCopy a System call?

Tags: java

Example

```
short size = 1234;
    byte[] payload = {12,43, 55,123, 11, 55};

byte [] shortSize = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(size).array();
byte[] entirePayload = new byte[shortSize.length+payload.length];   

System.arraycopy(shortSize, 0, entirePayload, 0, 2);
System.arraycopy(payload, 0, entirePayload, 2, payload.length);
```

Is there a underlying reason this is a Java System call?

Comment: Just because a function resides in the `System` class doesn't make it a "system call". `System` is just another Java class.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps `arraycopy` would have fitted better on [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), but that class wasn't added until Java 1.2, whereas `arraycopy` was there at the very beginning of Java. `System` seems like the next best place to have put it.

Note too that this method is implemented in native code to make it faster, so it is a bit special.

Comment: I generally don't like native methods that much. The Math.sin() is ridiculously slow.

Comment: @Legend: Okay, well think back to Java 1.1, when the VM was nothing but a lowly bytecode interpreter and all array accesses were always bounds-checked. You'd like System.arrayCopy plenty.

Comment: @Boann +1 Not to mention block copy operations that are completely outside of reach of regular Java code.